# Main.storyboard changing views every time I restart my computer

Tags: xcode, storyboard, swift3, xcode8

I'm actually getting a problem with my main.storyboard. Every time I restart my computer the main.storyboard is changing two UIViewController whose are embed with a segue to an UITableViewController. This happen since I update Xcode and swift to the lastest versions (Xcode8 and Swift3).

It's look like the constrain are changing the width and height of three elements inside the view (UIView, UIButton and MKMapView). I don't know why but the height and width of those elements change to 1000. Here a picture of my storyboard:

[image]

I would like to know if somebody is getting the same problem and how could I solve it or if I'm doing something wrong with the xcode configuration.

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fix this error by updating xcode8 to xcode 8.1, it seems it was a problem with the software.
Just have to readapt my elements to the respective constraints and all clear.